# Multiple instances of a *series* of beans?

Tags: java, spring

I know how to create multiple instances of *a* bean class. However, now I have a *series* of classes, say:

```
class AppleInModule {
  @Autowired RedisTemplate template; // <-- just any *external* dependencies
  @Autowired OrangeInModule orange; // <-- dependencies to *internal* classes of this package
  @Value("${the_module.apple.some_config_value}") String configValue; // <-- application.yml config values 
}

class OrangeInModule {
  ... // similar
}
```

Then, I want to create two *series* of instances, like:

> mymodule.apple_1 (its "orange" will be orange_1, and its "configValue" is "123"), mymodule.orange_1
>
> mymodule.apple_2 (its "orange" will be orange_2, and its "configValue" is "456"), mymodule.orange_2

Question: How to do that? Thanks very much!

Comment: What do you mean by series of beans, you can create any number of same class beans, you can register them with a different name in bean factory.

Comment: A little more detail about your use case will be helpful; there are a few different possible approaches.

Comment: By saying "a series" I mean a sub-module. This submodule contains lots of classes that depend on each other and also depend on external classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Qualifier` annotation to distinguish between two beans of the same class.
in your application context:

```
@Bean(name="orange1")
public OrangeInModule orange1() {
...
}

@Bean(name="orange2")
public OrangeInModule orange2() {
...
}
```

and in your wiring class:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("orange1")
private OrangeInModule orange1;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("orange2")
private OrangeInModule orange2;
```

Alternativly, if there are several instances and you just want to get all of them, you can autowire a list of `OrangeInModule`, it will hold all available beans of this class

Comment: Thanks! How to let apple1 automatically match orange1, apple2 match orange2?